# Can I use vue.js to change a css class?

Tags: vue.js

I have an MVC project and im using vue for my application form.

```
<div class="validation-error" ref="message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)</div>
<div class="label-container">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)</div>   
<div class="form-control">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { v_model = "val", @ref = "field" })</div>
```

which is a text box with a validation message bounded to it. Im wondering if I can change the colour of the text box only if the validation message is active.

I saw the html renders an attribute called `aria-invalid="true"` so im wondering if I could use `v-if` or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) section of the Vue.js documentation.

Here's an example of a class that is enabled or disabled based on the truthiness of a Vue.js variable:

```
<div :class="{ 'css-class-name': isActive }"></div>
```